# Flash is not supported for front camera, though stock Camera app has flash support for front camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

On Samsung S10 I can't enable flash using front camera (both camera2 and legacy camera API return `false` when checking support of flash for this camera)

For example

`Timber.d("flashSupport ${CameraUtil.isFlashAvailable(this, "0")}, ${CameraUtil.isFlashAvailable(this, "1")}")`

`"0"` - id of back camera
`"1"` - id of front camera

output:

> flashSupport true, false

```
fun isFlashAvailable(context: Context, cameraId: String): Boolean {
    val characteristics = getCameraCharacteristics(context, cameraId)
    return characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE) == true
}
```

So I can enable flash only for back camera but not for front camera? Why so? Samsung limits it and allows only for their system Camera app or is there something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [specs](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10-9536.php) of the Samsung S10, it doesn't appear to have a front-facing flash unit?

> MAIN CAMERA:  Triple  12 MP, f/1.5-2.4, 26mm (wide), 1/2.55", 1.4µm, Dual Pixel PDAF, OIS
> 12 MP, f/2.4, 52mm (telephoto), 1/3.6", 1.0µm, AF, OIS, 2x optical zoom
> 16 MP, f/2.2, 12mm (ultrawide), 1/3.1", 1.0µm, Super Steady video
>
> Features: LED flash, auto-HDR, panorama
> Video   4K@60fps (no EIS), 4K@30fps, 1080p@30/60/240fps, 720p@960fps, HDR10+, stereo sound rec., gyro-EIS & OIS

> SELFIE CAMERA: Single 10 MP, f/1.9, 26mm (wide), 1/3", 1.22µm, Dual Pixel PDAF
>
> Features: Dual video call, Auto-HDR
> Video   4K@30/60fps, 1080p@30fps

It's possible Samsung's camera app implements a 'flash' by turning the screen white and lighting up the user that way.  If so, you can implement the same thing in your own app.

But the camera API only lists regular flash units with an LED or other strobe light.

Comment: Yes, it seems they just set very high brightness. But here's another issue, Samsung has 4 cameras ids. "3" is second back camera (wide lens) and device reports that it also doesn't have flash but if I turn on flash for this camera without checking support it actually works if using Camera2, thought it doesn't work with legacy camera API (preview won't start, exception). So at least it's good that Camera2 is safe and we can set some key which may not be supported but it still will work or ignore. So flash works for two back cameras though API reports that only first back camera supports it